# Python Function to translate text

Tags: python, language-translation

Am new to python programming and am trying to work on an assignment to translate English text to French using a function in IBM Language Translator.
I get no output when I return the function  Please any help. Here is my code below:

```py
def englishToFrench(englishText):
    
    language_translator.set_service_url('url')

    frenchText = language_translator.translate(
        text='Hello, how are you today?',
        model_id='en-fr').get_result()

    return frenchText
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is a demo code from [IBM Language Translator Python Docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/language-translator?code=python#translate).

```
import json
from ibm_watson import LanguageTranslatorV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
language_translator = LanguageTranslatorV3(
    version='2018-05-01',
    authenticator=authenticator
)

language_translator.set_service_url('{url}')

translation = language_translator.translate(
    text='Hello, how are you today?',
    model_id='en-es').get_result()
print(json.dumps(translation, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

You need to go through the following steps to make it work:

1. Replace `{apikey}` and `{url}` with your service credentials.
2. `pip3 install ibm_watson` and `pip3 install ibm_cloud_sdk_core` to install Python modules. (Assuming you are using python3)

Look up [this link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/language-translator?topic=language-translator-gettingstarted) for more details.

Good luck